# Should 118 be read as 一百一十八 or 一百十八?

Tags: number

Should the number 118 be read as 一百一十八 or 一百十八?

A related question: How to read 2018年?

1. 两千零一十八年?
2. 二千零一十八年?
3. 二零一八年?
4. 两千零十八年?
5. 二千零十八年?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The year number is **always** read digit by digit, so 2018年 is read as 二〇一八年.

---

118 should be read as 一百一十八 in Standard Mandarin Chinese according to the mathematics textbooks in primary school, but the non-standard 一百十八 is also common.

Similarly, the number 2018 (without 年) should be read as 二千零一十八 in Standard Mandarin Chinese.

[image: mathematics textbook in primary school]

[image: mathematics textbook in primary school]

Comment: 一百十八 is not common...

Comment: @NS.X. It is pretty common, such as https://www.cangqionglongqi.com/xinghedadi/2511638.html

Comment: @NS.X. It's uncommon *nowadays*, but it used to be very prevalent in literal Chinese, e.g. chapter numbers in classical works (西游记、水浒传 etc)

Comment: @iBug Agreed...

Comment: @NS.X.  
https://www.zhihu.com/question/263505147/answer/271167817

Comment: @iBug 
https://www.zhihu.com/question/263505147/answer/776421173

Comment: @NS.X.  If you feel these expressions are uncommon, it means that you are too isolated in your hometown. 一百十八 and 一百一八 and even 百一八 are common in many places, although they are non-standard.

Comment: @Victor That 知乎 link isn't very argumentative: 一十 is a special case as almost everyone says 一百一十, 一千零一十 etc. But using 十八 directly following a bigger number isn't.

Comment: @iBug If you go to some other provinces, you may find that almost **no one** says 一百一十. Don't put your eyes only in your hometown. The *standard* expression is not so popular as you think.

Comment: @VictorV Mind suggesting an example? I'm not aware of anywhere where the usage of 一百一十 or 一百一 is a minority.

Comment: @iBug almost everywhere except 华北 and 东北

Comment: @Victor Perhaps a tour to the rural areas of all across China could help clear your doubt. I'm not going to convince you online. Keep what you think until you can verify them yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101182/discussion-between-victor-and-ibug).

Answer (score 1):

118 is read as: 一百一十八. Sometimes it could be: 一 一 八 as when we say telephone numbers.

2018 is 二零一八(年). We don't usually say 两千零一十八年， but we do say 两千零八年(2008). I don't have a good reason why though. Of course, 二零零八年 is also correct.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick comment: 二零零八 mean 2008.

Comment: If we say telephone numbers, then 118 should be 幺幺八。

Comment: @Victor Yeah 幺幺八 is more common. 一 一 八 is not wrong either.